# setting mailto links to open as html in iPhone/iPad HTML+JS app

Tags: iphone, email, ipad, mailto

The app is wrapped by PhoneGap, so I have access to change the C#.

I know mailto body is sent as plain text. I've read that in OS3 a flag can be set in with the MailComposerViewController class to send html emails.

I don't mind exiting the app to send an email. I just wondered if I could change a little bit of #C so that my HTML5+JS app can use mailto to send rich emails, which seems less work than using the MailComposerViewController and getting it to talk to PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

This guy has done an easy peasy to follow in app email plugin for PhoneGap:

http://github.com/purplecabbage/PhoneGap-Plugins/tree/master/EmailComposer

Google is not very helpful (on this occasion), which is why I'm posting the link.

Comment: Hey Owen, I find this plugin not so easy-peasy to follow, any chance there are some code samples out there? How do I launch this with jQuery Mobile in a Phonegap project?